# Gridview with: fixed header; sorting columns; values of a selected row in a gridview ordered

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="155px">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="FirstName"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="110px" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="LastName" ></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateMin" HeaderText="DateMin" ItemStyle-Width="110px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateMax" HeaderText="DateMax" ItemStyle-Width="110px" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="PhoneNumber"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="PhoneNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PhoneNumber")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Details" runat="server" Text="Details"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Details" runat="server" OnClick="details_Click" Text="Details">
            </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want:

1) add a scrollbar on x axis of the gridview with fixed header.

2) order this gridview by FirstName, LastName and PhoneNumber asc/desc.

3) If I click on element "Details" in any row, I need to access to all the column values in that row to memorize them in a particular object.

1) First problem solved like this:

I added a "div" element outside the gridview with: fixed width (also the gridview has fixed total width and fixed width for each item); fixed height;  "overflow:auto". I hid the header of the gridview. I added a table above the gridview with the new header. It works (even I if I think it is not an optimal solution).

```
<table style="height:30px;max-height:30px; background-color:#473BA3; border:1px; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:160px; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
           <asp:Label Text="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="orderFirstNameByIdAsc" runat="server" Text="&#x02191"  OnClick="SortMethod" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="FirstNameAsc"></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="orderFirstNameByIdDesc" runat="server" Text="&#x02193" OnClick="SortMethod" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="FirstNameDesc"></asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td style="width:110px; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <asp:Label Text="LastName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="orderLastNameByIdAsc" runat="server" Text="&#x02191" OnClick="SortMethod" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="LastNameAsc"></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="orderLastNameByIdDesc"  runat="server" Text="&#x02193"  OnClick="SortMethod"  CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="LastNameDesc"></asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
          <td style="width:105px; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <asp:Label Text="DateMax" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
         <td style="width:105px; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <asp:Label Text="DateMax"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="width:93px; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <asp:Label  Text="PhoneNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="orderPhoneNumberByIdAsc"  runat="server" Text="&#x02191"  OnClick="SortMethod" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="PhoneNumberAsc"></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="orderPhoneNumberByIdDesc"  runat="server" Text="&#x02193" OnClick="SortMethod"  CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="PhoneNumberDesc"></asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100px; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <asp:Label  Text="Details" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="height:350px; max-height:350px; width:905px; max-width:905px; overflow:auto;" >
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTest"  Width="885px" Height="100%" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="155px">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="FirstName"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FistName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="110px" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="LastName" ></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateMin" HeaderText="DateMin" ItemStyle-Width="110px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateMax" HeaderText="DateMax" ItemStyle-Width="110px" />
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="PhoneNumber"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="PhoneNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PhoneNumber")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Details" runat="server" Text="Details"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Details" runat="server" OnClick="details_Click" Text="Details">
                </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

2) Second problem:

MyElementList is a particular object with some elements.. It's not important in the exercise, so I called it "MyElementList" with a set of Element like "FirstName", "LastName".. etc.

```
protected void SortMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);      
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DateMin", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DateMax", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PhoneNumber", typeof(int)));

    foreach ("Element" dv in "MyElementList")
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["FirstName"] = dv.FirstName;
        dr["LastName"] = dv.LastName;
        dr["DateMin"] = dv.DateMin;
        dr["DateMax"] = dv.DateMax;
        dr["PhoneNumber"] = dv.PhoneNumber;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    if (dt != null)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        if (btn.CommandArgument.Contains("FirstName"))
        {
            if (btn.CommandArgument.Equals("FirstNameAsc"))
                dv.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", btn.CommandArgument.Substring(0, 9), "ASC");
            else if (btn.CommandArgument.Equals("FirstNameDesc"))
                dv.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", btn.CommandArgument.Substring(0, 9), "DESC");
        }
        else if (btn.CommandArgument.Contains("LastName"))
        {
            if (btn.CommandArgument.Equals("LastNameAsc"))
                dv.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", btn.CommandArgument.Substring(0, 8), "ASC");
            else if (btn.CommandArgument.Equals("LastNameDesc"))
                dv.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", btn.CommandArgument.Substring(0, 8), "DESC");
        }
        else if (btn.CommandArgument.Contains("PhoneNumber"))
        {
            if (btn.CommandArgument.Equals("PhoneNumberAsc"))
                dv.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", btn.CommandArgument.Substring(0, 11), "ASC");
            else if (btn.CommandArgument.Equals("PhoneNumberDesc"))
                dv.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", btn.CommandArgument.Substring(0, 11), "DESC");
        }
        GridViewTest.DataSource = dv;
        GridViewTest.DataBind();
    }
}
```

P.S. 
If I use

```
DataTable dataTable = GridViewTest.DataSource as DataTable;
```

instead of creating a new datatable, it doesn't work because of the "details" element in the GridViewTest.

If I use

```
GridViewTest.DataSource = MyElementList;
GridViewTest.DataBind();
GridViewTest.Sort("FirstName", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

I have an exception (I don't understand why).

3) Third problem (unsolved in efficient way):

I have the method

```
protected void details_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
}
```

Here I can't use grdrow.Cells[i].Text with i = 0,1,4 because the result is "". I need to find this element in MyElementList in a different index (because this has another order respect to the gridview).

Is there a way to have that value instead of search in myelementlist?

In general, is there a better way to have these three things in the same gridview?